# Why does cindent align statements to closing } in switch case?

Tags: indentation, filetype-c

I prefer this indentation style for switch cases with local variables:

```
switch (expr) {
case CONST_BLAH1: {
        int decl; // scope local to this case
        stmt;
        break;
case CONST_BLAH2: } {
        stmt;
        break;
case CONST_BLAH3: } {
        int x, y;
        stmt;
        break;
case CONST_BLAH4: }
        // because this is the last case we don't introduce new scope
        int x, y;
        stmt;
}
```

My current C-indentation options are:

```
set cinoptions=:0,l1,(s,m1
```

And Vim indents the code like this:

```
switch (expr) {
case CONST_BLAH1: {
        int decl;
        stmt;
        break;
case CONST_BLAH2: } {
        stmt;
        break;
case CONST_BLAH3: } {
        int x, y;
        stmt;
        break;
case CONST_BLAH4: } 
                  int x, y;
                  stmt;
}
```

Why does it align the statements in `CONST_BLAH4` to the previous closing `}`? And how do I remove this behavior?

Comment: This is a guess, but *I believe* that before ANSI C (1989) extra scopes inside the function were not allowed (or were proprietary extensions).  Original `vi` is from the late '70s, before ANSI C.  But I repeat, this is a *guess*.

Comment: After a quick search, it looks like [scopes are skipped](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/ba96e9af388804364425185b47eed14988302865/src/misc1.c#L8094-L8107) when searching for `case` in `switch` statements, which I think is reasonable. Just a guess, but I think the `cinoptions` parser only sees your first `case` expression.  Why aren't you closing the scope before the next `case`, anyways?

Comment: @TommyA Closing after the next `case` is a part of the coding style. Closing before the next `case` looks confusing when the case labels aren't indented.

Comment: @ryvnf, closing the braces after the case label is quite strange indeed. If in the block of `CONST_BLAH3` you do a `goto CONST_BLAH1`, you would be jumping inside a block that is going to be closed immediately. This would be at best inefficient. I know you are going to say you don't do `goto case_label`, the point is that this construct is just unnatural.